# How does c++ stl unordered_map print all its values?

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map

I am using the c++ stl unordered_map library for some leetcode question. I can use find function and [] operator overload to access my elements. but I've seen some answers using a for loop to iterate through all the elements of the hashmap. From my understanding the inner structure of a hashmap is a vector usually and this vector will never be fully used(meaning there will be empty slots to have constant big O from not having too much collision). But from the answers I am seeing people are iterating over the vector but they are not printing these empty indexes because I don't see any garbage values. I don't understand how this is possible. Here is the code i've seen.

```
vector<vector<string>> groupAnagrams(vector<string>& strs) {
        unordered_map<string, vector<string>> mp;
        for (string s : strs) {
            mp[t].push_back(s);
        }
        vector<vector<string>> anagrams;
        for (auto p : mp) {  //this is the part I don't understand
            anagrams.push_back(p.second);
        }
        return anagrams;
    }
```

I would expect iterating over each element of the underlying vector of the hashmap data structure to have garbage values because not all members are filled in the vector, but the result doesn't include these values and only gives the correct output. I don't understand how.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you don't need the first loop. Just do `mp[t] = strs;` to copy the full vector in one go instead.

Comment: wow I didn't know that was possible. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question, it seems like you might think that an iterator to an STL container iterates straightforwardly over the underlying data structure. That is not the case. The iterator itself can contain fields and logic to allow it to iterate in a logical manner.

The standard library doesn't dictate algorithm implementations, but all common can support iteration without going over empty elements:

1. The closed-table implementation you wrote about (which is not used in practice by implementations of the STL), has an array of entries, each of which is taken or not. Each entry can be marked as taken either by having an array of pairs (one for the value, and one for a boolean), or by using two arrays. In any case, when iterating, the iterator simply bypasses, when incremented, all entries that are not taken.
2. A more common implementation is an array of linked lists. Here, the iterator contains both the position within the array, and the link of the list. When incremented, it attempts to move to the next link. If none exists, it moves to the next list that is nonempty.

Comment: Thank you very much, can I ask in this case what does the auto equate to then?

Comment: That is an unrelated point. The `auto`, in this case, allows you to define a variable to be used to iterate over all values of an iterator. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: So would they have to overload some operator for it to return an iterator in this for loop? because in the basic for loop structure of (int i=0;i<hashmap.size();i++) i wouldn't know how to access these iterators

Comment: @OgiciBumKacar Yes, using `(int i=0;i<hashmap.size();i++)` is not the way to iterate over an unordered map, because it doesn't allow you access to the i-th element.

Comment: @OgiciBumKacar The `auto` is a [*placeholder type specifier*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) and is used for automatic type deduction by the compiler. In your specific case the compiler will deduce it to `unordered_map<string, vector<string>>::value_type`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Excellent explanation!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so would there be a way to write it in the basic for loop structure like the one I stated above? Or do I have to use autos?

Comment: @OgiciBumKacar A map doesn't have indexes, so you can only iterate over one using [range-based `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) (as shown in the question) or a "normal" `for` loop using iterators.